# How to run Tor as a bridge only (without being a client)

Tags: 14.10, tor

I want to configure my `/etc/tor/torrc` to be a bridge, but not to waste precious Tor bandwidth. Now I'm using Tor to everything (including email and Youtube) and I don't want this.

I'm wasting Tor, how can I configure my `/etc/tor/torrc` file as a bridge relay and make me stop being a client?

I use Ubuntu 14.10 and my `torrc` code is:

```
SocksPort 0
BridgeRelay 1
ORPort 9030
NickName foobar
ContactInfo foobar@example.com
AccountingStart month 7 00:00
AccountingMax 40 GBytes
RelayBandwidthRate 200 KBytes
RelayBandwidthBurst 500 KBytes
```

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [tor.se], although it isn't off-topic here.